# "Factor has new levels" error for variable I'm not using

Tags: r, r-factor, r-formula

Consider a simple dataset, split into a training and testing set:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), z=c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1))
train <- dat[1:4,]
train
#   x y z
# 1 1 a 0
# 2 2 b 0
# 3 3 c 1
# 4 4 d 0
test <- dat[5,]
test
#   x y z
# 5 5 e 1
```

When I train a logistic regression model to predict `z` using `x` and obtain test-set predictions, all is well:

```
mod <- glm(z~x, data=train, family="binomial")
predict(mod, newdata=test, type="response")
#         5 
# 0.5546394
```

However, this fails on an equivalent-looking logistic regression model with a "Factor has new levels" error:

```
mod2 <- glm(z~.-y, data=train, family="binomial")
predict(mod2, newdata=test, type="response")
# Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
#   factor y has new level e
```

Since I removed `y` from my model equation, I'm surprised to see this error message. In my application, `dat` is very wide, so `z~.-y` is the most convenient model specification. The simplest workaround I can think of is removing the `y` variable from my data frame and then training the model with the `z~.` syntax, but I was hoping for a way to use the original dataset without the need to remove columns.

Comment: In my case I had a bug in my code that made the model unstable. I was increasing weights of correctly classified instances and decreasing incorrectly classified instances. It should be the other way around...

Comment: I agree this is confusing behavior. model.frame doesn't seem to be able to ignore variables.

Comment: Even when `test$y` shows a factor with 5 levels, somehow `predict` doesn't consider that.

Comment: https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18619

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could try updating `mod2$xlevels[["y"]]` in the model object

```
mod2 <- glm(z~.-y, data=train, family="binomial")
mod2$xlevels[["y"]] <- union(mod2$xlevels[["y"]], levels(test$y))

predict(mod2, newdata=test, type="response")
#        5 
#0.5546394
```

Another option would be to exclude (but not remove) "y" from the training data

```
mod2 <- glm(z~., data=train[,!colnames(train) %in% c("y")], family="binomial")
predict(mod2, newdata=test, type="response")
#        5 
#0.5546394
```

Comment: These are both good options -- thanks! The behavior described in the post almost seems like a bug (I don't see why I should have to remove `y` from my dataframe with the second model specification), but these are sensible workarounds.

Comment: If you run `debug` on `glm` you can see where it's creating the model terms `mt <- attr(mf, "terms")`. I think `y` is being treated as if it's in the model because when you use `z~.-y` the formula expands to `z ~ (x + y) - y`, so `y` is technically in the model, but I don't have any other insight (just a work around :))

Comment: With dplyr: `train %>% select(-y)`

Answer (score 4):

We may **generalize *@matt_k's* great [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22315779/6574038)  to apply it to  high-dimensional data** where there are multiple factors with different levels in the `train`ing and `test` sets, like these:

```
dat2
#   x y1 y2 z
# 1 1  a  A 0
# 2 2  b  B 0
# 3 3  c  C 1
# 4 4  d  D 0
# 5 5  e  E 1
```

When we divide into test and training as before,

```
train <- dat2[1:4, ]
test <- dat2[5, ]
```

both `y1` and `y2` `test` levels will differ from those of `train` and we get the error.

```
mod <- glm(z ~ ., data=train, family="binomial")
predict(mod, newdata=test, type="response")
# Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
#   factor y1 has new level e
```

With high-dimensional data, it's rather boring to correct every single failing factor, so we might want to loop over them.

Either, the bad guys are of class `"factor"`, or of class `"character"` (as in our case). Since these will be the ones to be included in the 'xlevels', we use a small helper that identifies them,

```
is.prone <- function(x) is.factor(x) | is.character(x)
```

and put it into `Map`.

```
id <- sapply(dat2, is.prone)
mod$xlevels <- Map(union, mod$xlevels, lapply(dat2[id], unique))
```

Then it should work.

```
predict(mod, newdata=test, type="response")
#            5 
# 5.826215e-11 
# Warning message:
# In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = if (type ==  :
#   prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

---

```
dat2 <- structure(list(x = 1:5, y1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), y2 = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e"), z = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the tidymodels framework, [recipes](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/recipes/) has a way to exclude variables from modeling by changing their "role":

> Now we can add roles to this recipe. We can use the `update_role()` function to let recipes know that `flight` and `time_hour` are variables with a custom role that we called `"ID"` (a role can have any character value). Whereas our formula included all variables in the training set other than `arr_delay` as predictors, this tells the recipe to keep these two variables but not use them as either outcomes or predictors.

```
flights_rec <- 
  recipe(arr_delay ~ ., data = train_data) %>% 
  update_role(flight, time_hour, new_role = "ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about this issue for a long time. However, there was a simple solution to this. One of the variable "traffic type"  had 20 factors and for one factor ie 17 there was only one row. Hence this row could be present either in train data or test data. In my case it was present in test data hence the error came - factor "traffic type" has a new level of 17 because there is no row with level 17in train data. I deleted this row from data set and model runs perfectly fine

Comment: Hi Bhavna -- yes, for sure you can get this error if the test set has a new level for a factor you are using in the model, and removing that observation is a reasonable way to proceed. In this question I was specifically asking about a factor I was *not* using in the model but that just happened to be present in my data frame. In this setting, we shouldn't have to remove the observation from the test set, and matt_k gives some nice approaches.

Comment: Not really a solution... You cant just delete all unknown factors from a set.